# variable not working in function

Tags: javascript, variables

Why are these two codes in javascript different from each other? This is the first code:

```js
var string = "I am 21 years old. My number is 0799340540"
string += " and I am 19. My number is 0786432560";

var validate = /\d+/g;
var result;

while ((result = validate.exec(string)) != "null") {
  document.write(result[0] + "<br>");
}
```

and this is the second code

```js
var string = "I am 21 years old. My number is 0799340540"
string += " and I am 19. My number is 0786432560";

var validate = /\d+/g;
var result = validate.exec(string);

// while (result != "null") {
//  document.write(result[0] + "<br>");
//}

// the commented lines will create an infinite loop
```

Comment: I'd be more concerned with that infinite loop.

Comment: The expression in `while (...)` is evaluated at every iteration of the loop. In the second code, `validate.exec(string)` only runs once. In the first code, it runs repeatedly.

Comment: Can you please give more details how does the second code runs only once

Comment: Aside from other problems, your comparison is wrong. You need to compare to `null` (which in JS is an `object`), not `"null"` (which is a `String`).

Comment: @connexo `null` is not an object! (Despite what `typeof` says.) It cannot have properties.

Comment: Good to learn! Here's the details: http://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was stated in some of the comments, the difference essentially comes down to the fact that in the first code snippet, the regular expression is continuously evaluated until it reaches the end of the string, in the second one, it is evaluated once. What this results in your example is that the first one will execute the code in the while loop 4 times, then exit. Whereas the second one will be stuck in an infinite loop. For instance:

```
while((result = validate.exec(string)) != null){
    document.write(result[0] + "<br>");
}
```

WIll execute `validate.exec()` for every iteration if the loop, each time it searches the string from where it left off, untill it finally finishes the search and returns null, at this point the while condition is false and therefore it exits the loop.

Now in this code:

```
var result = validate.exec(string);

while(result != null){
    document.write(result[0] + "<br>");
}
```

`validate.exec()` is only executed once in the first line, and it returns an array containing information about the search. it is **not null**. So when your while loop runs, in every iteration of the loop it checks if `result != null`, and since nowhere in the loop are you updating the value of `result`, it will never change and so `result != null` will always evaluate to true, thereby never exiting the loop.

**UPDATE**

As was pointed out, you also need to correctly check for null, instead of comparing to the string value of "null", you need to compare to the primitive value of `null`. Updated the snippets above to reflect this.

Comment: You haven't fixed comparison to `"null"` (which should be `null`).